# Submitting only filled out Textboxes - C# ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

## Target Status

I have a `WebGrid` containing multiple TextBoxes which can be filled out but don't necessarily have to be. So to prevent a save-button in every row i just use one, so Javascript takes over the validation and returns only those values of filled out TextBoxes.

But i'm having some problems with Javascript when it comes to validating and passing the filled-out Textboxes to the Function SaveChanges.

---

## The WebGrid

This WebGrid contains some rows each containing three Textboxes.

```
WebGrid grid1 = new WebGrid(Model.StamfordRel, canPage: false, fieldNamePrefix: "g1", pageFieldName: "p1");

@grid1.GetHtml(
    headerStyle: "wg_header",
    columns: new[] {

        grid1.Column("GLUSDBT1_deploydate",
            header: "GLUSDBT1 Deploydate " + Html.SortDirection(ref grid1,"GLUSDBT1_deploydate"),
            format: (item) => Html.TextBox("GLUSDBT1", (object)item.GLUSDBT1_deploydate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "GLUSDBT1TxtBx"}),
            style: "width_deploydates"),

        grid1.Column("GLUSDBR1_deploydate",
            header: "GLUSDBR1 Deploydate " + Html.SortDirection(ref grid1,"GLUSDBR1_deploydate"),
            format: (item) => Html.TextBox("GLUSDBR1", (object)item.GLUSDBT1_deploydate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "GLUSDBR1TxtBx"}),
            style: "width_deploydates"),

        grid1.Column("GLUSDBP1_deploydate",
            header: "GLUSDBP1 Deploydate " + Html.SortDirection(ref grid1,"GLUSDBP1_deploydate"),
            format: (item) => Html.TextBox("GLUSDBP1", (object)item.GLUSDBT1_deploydate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "GLUSDBP1TxtBx"}),
            style: "width_deploydates"),
})
```

---

## The SQL Procedure

For this procdeure the `Deploydate` is the Parameter which should represent the value of any `TextBox` in the `WebGrid`. `LogNO` and `InstanceNO` are just id's.

```
PROCEDURE p_insert_stmfrd_rel_records(
                                      DeployDate  IN   DATE,
                                      LogNO       IN   NUMBER,
                                      InstanceNO  IN   NUMBER
                                     ) IS
    vNum number;
BEGIN
    select count(1)
    into vNum
    FROM ADM_DEPLOYMENTLOGDETAIL
     WHERE     INSTANCENO = InstanceNO
           AND LOGNO = LogNO
           AND DEPLOYDATE IS NOT NULL;
    IF vNum > 0
    THEN
        BEGIN
            UPDATE ADM_DEPLOYMENTLOGDETAIL
               SET DEPLOYDATE    = DeployDate
             WHERE     INSTANCENO = InstanceNO
                   AND LOGNO = LogNO;
        END;
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO ADM_DEPLOYMENTLOGDETAIL(
                                                LOGDETAILNO,
                                                DEPLOYDATE,
                                                STATUSID,
                                                CANCELEDIND,
                                                INSTANCENO
                                               )
                 VALUES (
                         ADM_DEPLOYMENTLOGDETAILNO_SQL.NEXTVAL,
                         DeployDate,
                         'D',
                         'N',
                         InstanceNO
                        );
        END;
    END IF;
END p_insert_stmfrd_rel_records;
```

---

## Current Procedure Call

```
public ActionResult SaveChanges(string deployDate)
{
    Convert.ToDateTime(deployDate);
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(Globals.Constants.AppConnectionStringReadOnly))
    {
        OracleCommand objcmd = new OracleCommand();
        objcmd.Connection = conn;
        objcmd.CommandText = "STAMFORDRELEASES.p_insert_stmfrd_rel_records";
        objcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        objcmd.Parameters.Add("DeployDate", OracleDbType.Date).Value = deployDate; // DeployDate
        objcmd.Parameters.Add("LogNO", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = 3; // LogNO / id
        objcmd.Parameters.Add("InstanceNO", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = 3; // InstanceNO / id
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(objcmd);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

Comment: Would it be a problem to check at server side which text boxes have values and then proceed with saving the appropriate info to database? Just posting them all and handling it later might be easier.

Comment: @Culme I don't know if this is a problem i just stuck to Javascript because normally there are just 5-10 Textboxes filled out of about 90'000 and i think handling it at the server side would decrease the speed quite a bit if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: If there are that many, you may be right. So you're displaying some 90k rows in the grid, and the user locates and fills out about 5-10 of them?

Comment: Yes its a multi user application with lots of filter functions and may people working on it

Comment: Why not show a submit button for each row then? It could be created/displayed only when all three textboxes on a row has been filled out, and submitted using ajax or similar. With that many rows, saving the user from having to scroll down 90k rows to find the submit button seems a good idea =)

Comment: The save button is fixed at the top

Comment: Got it. Question remains though, wouldn't it be a nice UI if the user fills out the three fields and then just tabs out to the submit button and posts that single row? You could locate the textboxes with JQuery/similar, and won't have to wade through all rows (in javascript either) to find the ones to submit. Sorry if I'm missing the point here.